# Changing values of an object inside a function

Tags: javascript

In the "superSecret" function “spy” will be passed in as an object that represents a spy. I want to loop through all the properties on the spy object and change all values to the string “redacted”, then return the updated spy object. Can someone look at my code and help me piece this together please?

```
var superSecret = function(spy){
  for(var i = 0; i < spy.length; i++) {
    "redacted"
    return 
}

var jamesBond = {
  eye: "brown",
  hair: "black",
  gun: "goldenGun",
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript objects are passed by reference, so you don't actually event need to return the object:

```js
var superSecret = function(spy){
  Object.keys(spy).forEach(function(key){
    spy[key] = 'redacted';
  });
}

var jamesBond = {
  eye: "brown",
  hair: "black",
  gun: "goldenGun",
}

superSecret(jamesBond);

console.log(jamesBond);
```

However if you'd like to preserve the original object and instead return a modified copy, you could use this:

```js
var superSecret = function(spy){
  var redacted = {};
  Object.keys(spy).forEach(function(key){
    redacted[key] = 'redacted';
  });
  return redacted;
}

var jamesBond = {
  eye: "brown",
  hair: "black",
  gun: "goldenGun",
}

var unknownHero = superSecret(jamesBond);

console.log(jamesBond);
console.log(unknownHero);
```